# Conda install Figtree

Tags: linux, anaconda, package, conda, phylogeny

Using Anaconda on Linux I tried this:

```
 conda install -c bioconda figtree
```

But it gives me this:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: | 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abor/ 
failed                                                                                                                                        

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
```

Maybe it's just me but isn't this an unhelpful message? What does `Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions`mean? Are they just trying to be mean?

Shouldn't I be searching for answers elsewhere? It does not seam right to ask here

And most importantly: how do I solve this and similar issues in the future? With or without Anaconda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bioconda has [channel configuration settings](https://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html#set-up-channels) that users need to follow in order to get the expected behavior from Bioconda packages including solving for installs. In particular, users should have **conda-forge** > **bioconda** > **defaults**. This could be what is affecting the installation, since `figtree` has `xorg-libxtst` as a dependency and that is only on Conda Forge.

If you want to do this *ad hoc* (as in OP), the command that would mimic their recommended settings would be

```bash
conda install --override-channels -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c defaults figtree
```

where the order of channels defines their precedence.

However, it is usually better practice to configure this either globally (what the Bioconda docs show) or on a per-environment basis (for users with a diversity of projects):

```bash
# activate environment
conda activate my_env

# set channels for environment
conda config --env --add channels defaults
conda config --env --add channels bioconda
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge

# no need to use ad hoc `-c` flags
conda install figtree
```

Comment: I am encountering a similar problem as well but your solution does not work for me.

Comment: @AngusCampbell you amy also need to set channel priority to strict. Otherwise, aska new question with exactly what you’ve tried.